# I Can Not Remove The Default Drop Down of a $has_one in Silverstripe

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I have tried:
    removeFieldFromTab
    removeByName
    replaceField

But the field persists.

```
use SilverStripe\ORM\DataObject;
use //.....

class Product extends DataObject {
    private static $db = [
        'ProductName'=>'Varchar',
        'TagLine'=>'Text',
        'GeneralDescription'=>'HTMLText'

    ];
    private static $has_one = [
        'SplashImage'=>Image::Class,
        'ProductCategory'=>ProductCategory::Class
    ];
    private static $has_many = [
        'ProductImage'=>Image::Class,
        'Features'=>'Feature'
    ];
    private static $owns = [
        'SplashImage',
        'ProductImage'
    ];
    private static $summary_fields = array(
        'ProductName'=>'Product Name'
    );   
    private static $searchable_fields = [

    ];
    public function getCMSFields(){
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();            

        $categoryField = DropdownField::create('ProductCategory', 'Choose Product Category', ProductCategory::get()->map('ID', 'ProductCategoryTitle'));            

        $fields->replaceField('ProductCategory', $categoryField);

        return $fields;     
    }
}
```

I am not getting any errors but the default drop down field that has the id #'s is at the top.

Comment: For reordering you can just use [changeFieldOrder](http://api.silverstripe.org/4/SilverStripe/Forms/FieldList.html#method_changeFieldOrder).

Comment: I don't need to reorder. I need to remove the default field and use my own.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `has_one` relations the field name should be `<RelationName>ID`, so in your case `ProductCategoryID`.

You have to reference the append ID to the relation name in order for SilverStripe to remove the field from the CMS tab by name.

```
$fields->removeByName('ProductCategoryID');
```

Also, if you create a custom field for a `has_one` relation, make sure you use `<RelationName>ID` as the name for the field. Eg. to create a Dropdown, use:

```
DropdownField::create(
    'ProductCategoryID', // Use RelationName + ID
    'Choose Product Category', 
    ProductCategory::get()->map('ID', 'ProductCategoryTitle')
);
```

Comment: That is not in the docs and doing: `'ProductCategory'=>'ProductCategoryID'` throws an error

Comment: I figured out what you mean from another answer. I needed "ProductCategoryID" in the removeByName method. Can you edit your answer so I can mark it correct. Thank you.