# Silverstripe drop down field does not show saved value as selected

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I have created a drop down field in the CMS like so:

```
class ProductPage extends Page {
    //.....

    private static $has_one = [
        'TeaserImage'=>Image::Class,
        'LinkedProduct'=>'Product'
    ];

    public function getCMSFields(){
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        $productLinkField = DropdownField::create('LinkedProduct', 'Link a Product', Product::get()->map('ID', 'ProductName'));
        $productLinkField->setEmptyString('(Select one)');

        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', $productLinkField, 'Content');

        return $fields;
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I select a value and save/publish the page the drop down goes back to "Select one" instead of showing the saved selection.

I have not checked the database to see if the value is being stored but I assume it is.

**EDIT:** Not a duplicate.
The suggested duplicate dealt with removing a field from the CMS.
This question deals with setting the drop down value to the saved selection.

The answers are however similar. The user must always append ID to a has_one field for the CMS to interact with it.

Comment: The answer is the same as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48029651/i-can-not-remove-the-default-drop-down-of-a-has-one-in-silverstripe/48035395#48035395

Comment: I need to add ID to the 'LinkedProduct' in the create statement?

Comment: Yep, that did it. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I updated the answer in the other question with that information

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I Can Not Remove The Default Drop Down of a $has\_one in Silverstripe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48029651/i-can-not-remove-the-default-drop-down-of-a-has-one-in-silverstripe)

Comment: I dont think it is a duplicate. It was my question, seems like I am the only one developing in Silverstripe. While the answers are similar, the problems were different between the two questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default SilverStripe appends an 'ID' parameter to the end of `has_one` relation fields when saving them in the database.

As such when you override the field for relations you will need to append 'ID' to the field identifier.

```
DropdownField::create('LinkedProductID', 'Link a Product', Product::get()->map('ID', 'ProductName'));
```